# aws s3: can't move/copy files from one folder to other

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have bucket A which has a couple of folders and a bunch of (root) objects.
I need to copy all folders from bucket A to bucket B, while the root objects will remain in bucket A.

I followed AWS instructions by selecting the folders in bucket A, hit "Actions"-"Cut", then navigating to bucket B, and hitting "Paste".

It all looked fine for a while. Then suddenly a whole series of `The following objects were not copied due to errors from: A` appeared.

What is extremely weird (and bad for me), is that it *did* move a few files, while the one resulting in errors just refuse to be moved.

I even assigned all rights to `Everyone` for the bucket policy for both buckets, thinking it may be a permission issue. Still, the files in question would not be moved. Copy also fails.
I am speechless. 
What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

The Amazon S3 management console offers a rudimentary Cut/Copy/Paste function. However, I wouldn't necessarily trust it for complex groups of objects.

A good way to copy/move files is by using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). For example:

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket1/path s3://bucket2/path --recursive
```

To move files between directories:

```
aws s3 mv s3://bucket1/path s3://bucket1/path2 --recursive
```

Comment: Thanks John. I forgot to add to the question that I actually DID try your proposal. Here's what I got: `copy failed: s3://bucket1/2016/10/21/file.png to s3://bucket2/2016/10/21/file.png An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CopyObject operation: Access Denied` - which I can't understand as I have the role `Everyone` with all permissions on both buckets! Why would I get an Access Denied now?

Comment: So, the question is whether the access was denied on the **source**, or whether it was denied on the **destination**. Can you try copying From and To the same bucket, but to a different path? That way you can check which bucket has unwanted permissions, then we can drill-down on the policies.

Comment: `aws s3 cp --recursive s3://bucket1/2016/10/21/ s3://bucket1/test` fails with same error message. `aws s3 cp --recursive s3://bucket2/2016/10/2 s3://bucket2/test` succeeds. Note that the above bucket2 operation is on a different path though. Anyway, it seems related to bucket1.

Comment: If you know one of the files on which it is failing, you can try updating the permissions on that file via an in-place copy: `aws s3 cp s3://key s3://key --acl bucket-owner-full-control` Believe it or not, assigning an IAM permission to do anything with S3 doesn't necessarily let you do everything if the object-specific permissions don't allow it.

Comment: thanks for your patience and willingness to help John. I understand what you are saying, and indeed I am missing operations on S3 which I would expect - like overriding all perms if I am the owner of the bucket. In any case -  trying what you suggests returns: `fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden`

Comment: Sounds to me like permissions on the objects are a bit confused. I've seen this where objects are created that don't grant permissions to the Bucket Owner. Yes, it really is possible to create files that the bucket owner can't access. Even a Bucket Policy doesn't grant access in some cases. I wonder if you can use Root credentials to force permissions via `--acl bucket-owner-full-control`? If you are subscribed to AWS Support, contact them for advice on the best way to resolve.

Comment: yep. the Cut/Copy/Paste function from UI console have lots of problems. Sometimes i can copy from cli but can't copy from console.